# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre un iterador failfast y failsafe en JAVA?

Tags: java

Mi pregunta es mas conceptual, eh estado buscando respuestas sobre esta pregunta pero no las estoy entendiendo.
¿Cual es la diferencia y que significan en cada caso?.
¿Pueden dar ejemplos?
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La diferencia es el comportamiento que tienen frente a la modificación concurrente.

Antes de empezar, ten en cuenta que la implementación de estos comportamientos depende de cada clase y no es común, por lo que lo que sigue está en términos generales:

### ¿Qué es *fail-fast*?

*Fail-fast* es un comportamiento de los `Iterator` de una colección. Implica que el `Iterator` **comprueba de forma agresiva que la colección subyacente no ha sido modificada desde que se empezó a iterar**, y en Java se lanza la [`ConcurrentModificacionException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

Imagina que tienes dos hilos actuando sobre una lista. El primero se dedica a leerla, y el segundo la modifica. Si el `Iterator` del primero tiene comportamiento *fail-fast*, cada vez que se llame a métodos que avancen la posición del `Iterator` se comprueba que la lista no haya sido modificada. En nuestro ejemplo, el segundo hilo ha modificado la lista, así que se lanzará la excepción.

#### ¿Cómo se implementa en Java?

*Fail-fast* se implementa con un **contador de modificaciones**. La colección tiene este contador y se pasa su valor al `Iterator`. Cuando se llama a los métodos que avanzan la posición, el `Iterator` comprueba que los valores de los contadores no difieran. Si difieren, se lanza la excepción.

#### Un ejemplo

Las colecciones no concurrentes del JDK son un ejemplo de *fail-fast* aunque en la documentación de las clases que implementan se especifica claramente que este comportamiento **no está asegurado**.

Un ejemplo con `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(3);

Iterator<Integer> iterator = numbers.listIterator();        
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
    numbers.add(4);  // Modificacion de la lista mientras se itera
}
```

Output:

```
1
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at 
java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:891)
    at SOE.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

### ¿Qué es *fail-safe*?

*Fail-safe* es otro comportamiento de un `Iterator`. Este comportamiento implica que el `Iterator` **se *protege* de modificaciones concurrentes, y por mucho que se modifique la colección subyaciente, la iteración no se verá afectada** y no se lanzará ninguna excepción.

En nuestro ejemplo, el `Iterator` del primer hilo no se vería afectado por las modificaciones del segundo hilo y tu programa continuaría ejecutándose sin Excepciones.

#### ¿Cómo se implementa en Java?

Esto es un poco más complicado, porque en la documentación de Java no aparece el comportamiento *fail-safe*. Lo más parecido es la *consistencia débil*. La forma en la que se suele implementar esto es que el `Iterator` opera sobre una *copia* de la colección subyaciente, creada en el momento de creación del `Iterator`. De esta manera, todas las modificaciones que se hagan a la colección original no afectarán a tu iteración.

#### Un ejemplo

Las colecciones de `java.util.concurrent` suelen aplicar este comportamiento. Un ejemplo con `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
ConcurrentMap<String,String> capitales = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
capitales.put("España", "Madrid");
capitales.put("Francia", "Paris");
capitales.put("Alemania", "Berlin");

Iterator<String> iterator = capitales.keySet().iterator();  // Se crea una copia

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(capitales.get(iterator.next()));
    capitales.put("Inglaterra", "Londres");  // Modificacion del map mientras se itera
}
```

Y el output:

```
Paris
Madrid
Berlin
```

Curiosamente, si pruebas a poner como claves de un `ConcurrentMap` enteros, la modificación sí se realiza. Supongo que esto tiene que ver con el *hashing* y que la implementación de `ConcurrentHashMap` permite la modificación concurrente con determinados tipos de claves.

En todo caso, esto debería servir como ejemplo de lo que puse al principio: Las implementaciones dependen de cada clase y para conocerlas en profundidad deberás leerte la documentación y el código fuente.